# What is the cause of this huge “other” data on Macintosh HD?

Tags: hard-drive, mac

I was doing large file transfers between internal and external drives on my iMac, and afterwards I saw a large chunk of the Macintosh HD used up for no apparent reason. (I don’t know how long it has been there).[image: Image showing contents of Macintosh HD] I don’t know how this got there, but it’s preventing from creating a large enough partition on Macintosh HD. For the full picture, I need to make a partition so that Macintosh HD is less than 500 Gb so that it can cloned to a 500Gb SSD. Thanks for any help!

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5353/85275

Comment: I don’t think this applies to my situation.

Comment: Reasonable cloning tools should allow you to clone to a smaller partition (as long as the space *used* is small enough to fit). If you're planning to clone it with something like `dd`, please just don't. Oh, and of course it's always best to make sure you have a backup of anything important before doing anything potentially dangerous like repartitioning.